# What does slow ring from Windows Insider program exactly mean?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, insider-preview

I have chosen for Slow Ring in Windows Insider App, i do receive updates from Slow Ring when it is available.

Currently my phone is showing slow ring 10.0.14342.1004 is available for download. When i search it on wikipedia it shows this update contains below things,

Bug fixes

- Fixes for battery life issues
- Fixes for device heating issues

I am really confused on what does this slow ring updates exactly releases.

**Does it contain only fixes listed as above or it releases all features/fixes released in previous Fast Rings?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does it contain only fixes listed as above or it releases all
>   features/fixes released in previous Fast Rings?

It contains the features released in the **previous builds** for Fast rings.

> When i search it on wikipedia it shows this update contains below
>   things,
>
> Bug fixes

The version 10.0.14342.1004 contains only the bug fixes as you told. But you must remember that Windows 10 updates are cumulative. This means that if you are installing the update 14342.1004 you will recieve all the features released before that build along with the update. Wikipedia is showing only what that particular build has fixed.

**This is how slow ring works**

For example, the build 14342.1001 was released for Fast rings. It adds new features to the OS. Now the bugs will be idenfied and fixed and the update 14342.1004 is released. This particular update will only contain bug fix.

Now this build is released for Slow rings. The update 14342.1004 will include all previous updates as updates are cumulative. So you will get the features introdced in 14342.1001.

**How does it happen?**

Windows 10 updates are cumulative. This means that a later update will contain all previously released updates which are not yet installed.

**So how do get the complete change log?**

If you want to know the complete change log, do the following,

1. Identify which build are you running by viewing in the about page of settings. (consider it as 14356.1001)
2. Go to wikipedia and check all the builds after 14356.1001 till the build number mentioned in the update(14356.1004).
3. If there are 2 builds released in between them then you will get all the features intorduced in those two builds along with the bug fixes.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Just verified, Fast Ring#10.0.14322.1000 has released one feature, "Camera button replaces the back button on the Lock screen", which i can now see on my start screen after installing Slow Ring#10.0.14342.1004. That was the first Fast Ring after previous slow ring#10.0.14295.1005 which was released on March 30, 2016.

Comment: @DineshM I'm glad that you find this answer helpful

Answer (score 1):

There are three rings ( or sections) in windows insider program.
fast ring/release preview rings gets the builds first , these are usually for testers. Fast ring deals with redstone updates( latest 14356.1000) and release preview deals with threshold updates (latest 10586.338)

> will this slow ring have all features/fixes from previous fast rings?

Slow ring insiders receives these builds only after fast ring users, if the feedback is very bad, slow ring insiders may not receive the update, and if the feedback is avg or good, they'll receive it.

Yes mostly they recieve it, but some features will be omitted , for eg; there were an option to hav 16 background processes running but this feature was omitted for slow ring when same build was released to them. Features that receive bad feedback will get axed!

Comment: yup i am aware about that. But my question is will the slow ring release have all features/fixes released as part of previous fast rings? Like in my case, version 10.0.14342.1004 have only 2 fixes for which slow ring is available but there have been so many fast rings released prior to that for which no slow ring is available. So will this slow ring have all features/fixes from previous fast rings?

Comment: Yes mostly, but some features will be omitted , for eg; there were an option to hav 16 background processes running but this feature was omitted for slow ring when same build was released to them. Features that receive bad feedback will get axed!